# How to use a capture variable as a field name in JQ?

Tags: regex, jq, pcre

I'm trying to use `jq` to automate changing i18n string files from the format taken by one library to another.

I have a json file which has looks like this:

```
{
  "some_label": {
    "message": "a string in English with a $VARIABLE$",
    "description": "directions to translators",
    "placeholders": {
      "VARIABLE": {
        "content": "{variable}"
      }
    }
  },
  // more of the same...
}
```

And I need that to turn in to `"some-label": "a string in English with a {variable}"`

I am pretty close to getting it.  Currently, I'm using

```
jq '[.                                                                                                                                                                            
    | to_entries 
    | .[] 
    | .key |= (gsub("_";"-")) 
    |  .value.placeholders as $p 
    | .value.message |= (sub("\\$KEY_NAME\\$";$p.KEY_NAME.content)) 
    | .value = .value.message
   ] | from_entries'
```

The next step is to use a capture group in the `sub` call so I can programmatically get variables with different names, but I'm not sure how to use the capture group to index into `$p`.

I've tried `sub("\\$(?<id>VARIABLE)\\$";$p.(.id).content)` which gave a compiler error, and I'm pretty much stuck on what to try next.

Comment: That's just an example to show the schema of the larger JSON value it's a part of.  I updated the example to be more explicit

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way of achieving the desired result. It could be simplified further too. At the top level it removes the usage of `to_entries`/`from_entries` by enclosing the whole filter under `with_entries()` and modifying the `.value` field as required

```
with_entries(
  .key |= ( gsub("_";"-") )  |
  .value.placeholders as $p  |
  .value.message as $m       |
  ( $m | match(".*\\$(.*)\\$") | .captures[0].string ) as $c |
  ( $p | .[$c].content ) as $v |
  ( "\\$" + $c + "\\$" ) as $t     |
  .value = ( $m | sub($t; $v) )
)
```

My view of the key parts of the expression are

1. The part `$m | match(".*\\$(.*)\\$") | .captures[0].string` makes a regex match to extract the part within the `$..$` in the `.message`
2. The part `$p | .[$c].content` does a generic object index fetch using the dynamic value of `$c`
3. Since the first argument of `sub()`/`gsub()` functions are a regex, the value captured `$c` needs to be created as `\\$VARIABLE\\$`

[jqplay - Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/JCQVo3IMB1)

Comment: This only outputs the last entry in the JSON.  Seeing `$p | .[$c].content` is what I was looking for though!  I'll keep working on the general case -- I also still need to deal with multiple variables yet

Comment: No wait -- I think it only selects entries which have variables -- some don't

Comment: @JonCohen: I tried to answer your question based on the inputs provided. It works exactly as shown in your desired output. If there is more complicated example, you should have updated it beforehand

Comment: I didn't mean to disparage your response! I just wanted help with this one step, which you gave me.  I appreciate it and thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Here's a basic JQ. Haven't tried with complex inputs, and haven't accommodated for `$`. I guess you can build on top of this -

```
to_entries | map(. as $kv | { "\($kv.key)": $kv.value.placeholders | to_entries | map(. as $p | $kv.value.message | sub("\\$\($p.key)\\$"; $p.value.content))[0]}) | add
```

output -

```
{
  "some_label": "a string in English with a {variable}"
}
```

Comment: @Inian I know. Shouldn't OP build on top of this instead of providing the entire solution? I can change my answer to a comment. The objective is to show variable replacement.

Comment: I have updated my answer to match better with OP's expectations.